# JavaScript: Arguments with more than one value

Tags: javascript, function

This function loops through JavaScript nested arrays (recursively) and replaces the strings inside them:

```
function replaceRecur(tree, str, newStr) {
  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i])) {
      replaceRecur(tree[i], str, newStr)
    } else {
      tree[i] = tree[i].replace(str, newStr)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
function replaceQuotes(tree, callback) {
  var str1 = /"(?=\b)/g
    , str2 = /"(?!\b)/g
    , newStr1 = '“'
    , newStr2 = '”'

  replaceRecur(tree, str1, newStr1)
  replaceRecur(tree, str2, newStr2)

  callback(null, tree) 
}
```

How should I modify `replaceRecur`  so I allow two values per argument?

Example:

```
function replaceQuotes(tree, callback) {
  var str = ['/"(?=\b)/g/', '"(?!\b)/g']
    , newStr = '“ ”' // not sure whether to use arrays or strings
                     // what's more common?

  replaceRecur(tree, str, newStr)

  callback(null, tree) 
}
```

(The reason is, I don't want to repeat `replaceRecur`, `str`, and `newStr` twice. I want to keep the code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).)

**EDIT:**

Example input (just in case):

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', '“a paragraph”' ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', '\'another paragraph\'' ],
  [ 'para', 'test--test' ],
  [ 'para', 'test---test' ],
  [ 'bulletlist',
    [ 'listitem', '“a list item”' ],
    [ 'listitem', '“another list item”' ] ] ]
```

Comment: I would think that your code is already dry. You are not repeating yourself, you call a function multiple times with different arguments? If at all use a loop in `replaceQuotes`.

Comment: I'm with @Bergi, just calling a function twice doesn't mean you're repeating yourself. And adding complexity to a simple function to avoid it isn't necessarily a good idea.

Comment: @Bergi Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function that performs the recursive traversal of the structure and invokes callbacks for values. Then you can write your replacement functions as callbacks you pass in to that:

```
function traverse(tree, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i]))
      traverse(tree[i], callback);
    else
      tree[i] = callback(tree[i]);
  }
}

function replaceTwo(tree, s1from, s1to, s2from, s2to) {
  traverse(tree, function(element) {
    return element.replace(s1from, s1to).replace(s2from, s2to);
  });
}
```

You can now write all sorts of different functions to transform tree contents without having to rewrite the recursion part.

Comment: plus1 -  `traverse` is much more useful than a `replaceRecur` that goes deep.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no overloading in JavaScript.

One clean solution would to use `replaceRecur` but internally check the `typeof` arguments to determine whether you want to use `_replaceRecur2` or `_replaceRecur1`

```
function replaceRecur(tree, arg1, arg2) {
  if(typeof(arg1) === "function"){
    _replaceRecur2(tree, arg1);
  } else {
    _replaceRecur1(tree, arg1, arg2);
  }
}

function _replaceRecur1(tree, str, newStr) {
  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i])) {
      _replaceRecur1(tree[i], str, newStr)
    } else {
      tree[i] = tree[i].replace(str, newStr)
    }
  }
}

function _replaceQuotes2(tree, callback) {
  var str1 = /"(?=\b)/g
    , str2 = /"(?!\b)/g
    , newStr1 = '“'
    , newStr2 = '”'

  _replaceRecur1(tree, str1, newStr1)
  _replaceRecur1(tree, str2, newStr2)

  callback(null, tree) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> not sure whether to use arrays or strings

Use arrays, you might want to replace multiple things. And you wouldn't alter `replaceRecur`, it is fine as it is. Rather introduce a new function

```
function replaceMultipleRecur(tree, strArr, newStrArr) {
    … // (in the simplest occasion a loop over the arrays with calls to replaceRecur)
}
function replaceQuotes(tree) {
    return replaceMultipeRecur([/"(?=\b)/g, /"(?!\b)/g], ['“', '”']);
}
```

> I don't want to repeat replaceRecur, str, and newStr twice

You can simply use your exsting function, by passing a regex that matches all your cases and a [replacer callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) instead of strings.

```
function replaceQuotes(tree) {
  replaceRecur(tree, /("\b)|("\B)/g, function(m, l, r) {
      return l ? '“' : '”';
  });
  return tree
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to abstract your code a bit more, here's one possible way:

```js
function maprec(x, callback) {
    return x.map ? x.map(function(x) {
        return maprec(x, callback);
    }) : callback(x);
}

function pipe() {
    var fns = arguments;
    return function(x) {
        return [].reduce.call(fns, function(a, f) { return f(a) }, x);
    }
}

// test/demo:

tree = ['foo "bar" !', ['baz', ['ccc "hi" ', 'd']], 'eee', ['"foo?"']];

converted = maprec(tree, pipe(
    function(x) { return x.replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '{') },
    function(x) { return x.replace(/"(?=\B)/g, '}') }
));

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(converted));
```

Ok, what we did here? First, we define `maprec`, a recursive mapper, which is the same as `map`, but respects nested structures. The second utility, `pipe`, is the function composer that takes a bunch of functions and returns a new function that applies these functions, in order, to the argument, in way similar to unix pipelines like `grep | sort | uniq` (hence the name). Note that this is different from the usual `compose`, which is right-associative. Finally, we use `maprec(tree, pipe(replacer1, replacer2))` to do the actual job.

(I use `{}`'s instead of fancy quotes to make them look more obvious in the console window).

To illustrate the power of pipelining, here's a more advanced example:

```
fancyQuotes = pipe(
    function(x) { return x.replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '&laquo;') },
    function(x) { return x.replace(/"(?=\B)/g, '&raquo;') }
);

trim = "".trim.call.bind("".trim);

wrap = function(x) { return this.replace(/\$/g, x)};
wrap.in = wrap.bind;

converted = maprec(tree, pipe(
    fancyQuotes,
    trim,
    wrap.in("<p>$</p>")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I'm with Bergi re his [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968752/javascript-arguments-with-more-than-one-value/28968849#comment46189228_28968752), just calling a function twice doesn't mean you're repeating yourself. And adding complexity to a simple function to avoid calling it twice isn't necessarily a good idea.

---

But to your question: You could just add two arguments to the function, ignoring them if not given:

```
function replaceRecur(tree, str1, newStr1, str2, newStr2) {
  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i])) {
      replaceRecur(tree[i], str1, newStr1, str2, newStr2);
    } else {
      tree[i] = tree[i].replace(str1, newStr1);
      if (typeof str2 !== "undefined") {
        tree[i] = tree[i].replace(str2, newStr2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In fact, you can just keep doing this endlessly using a loop.

```
function replaceRecur(tree, str, newStr/*, str2, newStr2, ...*/) {
  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i])) {
      replaceRecur.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      for (var arg = 1; arg + 1 < arguments.length; arg += 2) {
        tree[i] = tree[i].replace(arguments[arg], arguments[arg + 1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that on some JavaScript engines using the `arguments` pseudo-array has a negative impact on performance. On modern engines it doesn't matter at all.

Usage:

```
replaceRecur(tree, /"(?=\b)/g, '“', /"(?!\b)/g, '”');
```

Answer (score 0):

just alter the `else` to apply each regex in the array.

```
else {
    //array is the array of regex's passed
    array.forEach(function(item) {
        tree[i] = tree[i].replace(item, newStr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could put this in context in some way, as is it's fairly unclear and replaces **all** of the "source" strings with the full target string. If this is  meant to follow on from the OP's partial attempt, it fails to do so.

Comment: Its not following on, its pseudocode and a step in the right direction